# 'Unidentified network' on D-Link, unable to contact DHCP server

Tags: networking

I'm running Windows 8 Pro and have a D-Link DSL 2640-T connected to a D-Link DGE-528T. The relevant lights on both devices are blinking in a normal activity pattern. I also have an onboard wireless card that is connected to the same router (I'm using it to be on the Internet right now).

The adapter for this network card on Windows shows 'Unidentified Network'. Its autoconfiguration IPv4 address is 169.254.164.112, however the DHCP addresses range the router has to give away is 10.1.1.2 - 10.1.1.34. If I try to `ping 10.1.1.1` with the wireless connection disabled, it gives me 'Destination Host Unreachable'.

On a hail mary pass, I tried the approach from [Unidentified network: How to configure TCP/IPv4 for Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/253866/unidentified-network-how-to-configure-tcp-ipv4-for-windows-7) and did `route delete 0.0.0.0` and then `ipconfig /renew`. After about one minute, it gave the message `An error occurred while renewing interface Ethernet 2 : unable to contact your DHCP server. Request has timed out.` The wireless connection did get an IP, though, and continues working as usual.

I don't know how to continue troubleshooting this. Is it possible there's something wrong with the router?

Comment: Why is the router configured to pass out 10.1.1.x addresses? Most use 192.168.1.X

Comment: I really don't remember if I set it up this way (I have had this router for 3 or 4 years), but I don't think I changed the default setting. How is this relevant? Other devices in the same network (e.g. my notebook and the wireless card on the same computer) get their addresses from DHCP with no problems.

Comment: Updating, I performed a factory reset (holding the side reset button for 7 seconds) and the router IP kept on being 10.1.1.1

Comment: Was just curious, never saw that 10.1 before. According to the user manual the default address should be 192.168.1.1.......http://207.150.194.182/resources/user_manuals/DSL-2640T_B3(RoHS)%20_Manual.pdf

Comment: I found that manual too. I actually found it strange that the IP was different from the manual, but the factory reset did work otherwise: configurations lost, network renamed, etc. Only the router IP and the DHCP IP range was different from the expected default. I don't know why, I don't remember having updated the firmware or something.

Comment: I would change it to the default 192.168.1.1